# How can i use id's value in url?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http

How can i use id's value in url?

```
 $scope.modify = function (id) {
                    $http({
                        method: "POST",
                        url: prefixSeverUrl + "/" + "vehicles/id",
                        dataType: "json",
                        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
                        data: $scope.modifyvehicle,
                    })
```

Comment: url: prefixSeverUrl + "/" + "vehicles/id="+id  or if you don't want directly pass you can do like this:  url: prefixSeverUrl + "/" + "vehicles/" + id

Comment: `url: prefixSeverUrl + "/vehicles/" + id`

Comment: also you can try this `method:'POST',
        url: prefixSeverUrl , params: {id:idValue}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Concatenate the strings, like so:

`url: prefixSeverUrl + "/" + "vehicles/" + id,`

With JavaScript [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) you can use the following syntax:

```
url: `${prefixSeverUrl}/vehicles/${id}`
```